# Clarification about ArrayList syntax

Tags: java, syntax, arraylist, foreach

What is being done in this `for` loop, `counter` and `arr` are two different ArrayLists.

```
// 3. store count of each number as we iterate through arr
for(int i = 0; i< arr.size(); i++){
    counter[arr.get(i)]++;
}
```

Comment: You mean counter is an array and arr is an ArrayList, right?

Comment: can you elaborate your que?

Answer (score 3):

`arr` contains indexes that the corresponding elements for them on `counter` should be incremented.

For example:

```
arr = [1,3,4]
```

Then the elements in 1,3 and 4 will be incremented in the array `counter`.

I highly recommend you to debug your code to better understand the flow of the program. You should also be careful with [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html):

```
for(int i = 0; i< arr.size(); i++) {
    if(arr.get(i) < 0 || arr.get(i) >= counter.length) {
        continue;
    }
    counter[arr.get(i)]++;
}
```

Or doing something else, depends on the logic of your program.

Answer (score 0):

If `arr` contains integer numbers it is index of `counter` array. Then you are incrementing the value of `counter` array on `arr.get(i)` index. I hope you understand what I am saying.